# Minimum JARs to use MethodBeforeAdvice, MethodInterceptor, MethodBeforeAdvice usage

Tags: spring, jar, aop, spring-aop

What are the minimum JARs required from the Spring distribution and otherwise to make an application that uses `MethodBeforeAdvice`, `MethodInterceptor`, `MethodBeforeAdvice` work?

Answer (score 0):

spring-aop.jar and aopalliance-1.0.jar. spring-aop depends on asm.jar

As Donal noted, you need cglib only of you are having spring make proxies of concrete classes without an interface.

Comment: When I try to compile my Application that uses MethodBeforeAdvice, MethodInterceptor, MethodBeforeAdvice I seem to find that the following are absolutely mandatory: asm-3.1.jar, aspectjrt.jar, aspectjweaver.jar, cglib-2.2.2.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar. Are these replaced by aopalliance-1.0.jar

Comment: @TheLameProgrammer in maven the dependencies say that spring aop depends on aopaliiance and asm only. But usually you need aspectj features as well. But it is not mandatory.

Comment: @TheLame: You don't need cglib if you're able to consistently use proxies generated by interface (depends on your Spring config) but I've been happier using cglib. I've also been happier when I've just used Maven to acquire/build all the dependencies for me instead of trying to manually build minimum sets.